# How to specify dataset name when working with BigQuery JDBC

Tags: google-bigquery

When working with BigQuery's JDBC driver, is there a SQL construct, connection string option, or account configuration setting that I can use to select my default dataset to avoid prefixing all tables with their dataset names in queries?

E.g. something equivalent to a USE DATABASE ... command in a session, or to a default-schema setting in a connection string?   I know that the .bigqueryrc file supports this when using the CLI, but I can't find a way to do it from JDBC...

Answer (score 0):

Their guide is here, but looks like it's not supported.
http://cdn.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/Simba_BigQuery_ODBC_InstallGuide.pdf